# SQL Server : select parent/children to nth degree

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am attempting to select each possible child of a single parent record from two tables.

Table one holds all of the accounts with the current owner and the parent owner
Table two is the table that holds the relations between the parents and children.
so far I have managed just to select the main parent.

What I am unable to figure out is how to deal with the children and grandchildren

Table structure for example:

Table Accounts:

```
accountId | name | last name | email | OwningBusiness
```

Table Relations:

```
BusinessUnit | unitname | ParentBusinessUnit

OwningBusiness <=> BusinessUnitId
OwningBusiness <=> parentGroupOwner
```

My main goal is to select the entire tree where the root is the base parent.
how can I formulate a query that will get all accounts from the parent group then will check who are the children, select all the accounts from the children, and will keep doing this until all possible children/grandchildren have been checked?

Edit:
The search should be based on a given ParentBusinessUnit and should return only the account records with all the columns from the accounts table
Example Data:

```
OwningBusinessUnit                 ParentBusinessUnit
7C6A387E-4231                         113D3FDB-7B8E
A871C1DB-9B49                         7C6A387E-4231
99E668AC-E183                         113D3FDB-7B8E
61E240E0-5FDB                         964467C5-5EDB
DF12F932-60DB                         964467C5-5EDB
1A836362-883E                         CB52AEC3-9EA2
CDBF825B-51D6                         113D3FDB-7B8E
C7839193-51D6                         CDBF825B-51D6
F8831375-51D6                         CDBF825B-51D6
BEA96E00-7675                         113D3FDB-7B8E
556A4549-7675                         BEA96E00-7675
E4FD4238-A4F0                         E178822F-AF63
6CFE118A-62B0                         113D3FDB-7B8E
```

By using the following query I have made the intersection to provide the above data

```
select a.OwningBusinessUnit, bu.ParentBusinessUnit from Accounts a
inner join Relations bu on a.OwningBusinessUnit = bu.BusinessUnitId
group by bu.ParentBusinessUnit, a.OwningBusinessUnit
```

Requested result:
Providing the ParentBusinessUnit "113D3FDB-7B8E" as a parameter should find all
accounts in: "113D3FDB-7B8E" , "7C6A387E-4231", "99E668AC-E183", "CDBF825B-51D6", "A871C1DB-9B49" Etc

**EDIT 2:**
Following the answer, I have made the following changes:

```
declare @root nvarchar(50) = '113D3FDB-7B8E';
with rcte as
(
  select 
    br.Name buName,
    br.BusinessUnit,
    br.ParentBusinessUnit,
    a.*
  from BusinessUnitBase br
  join AccountBase a on a.OwningBusinessUnit = br.BusinessUnit
  where br.ParentBusinessUnit = @root and br.IsDisabled = 0
union all
  select 
  r.*
  from rcte r
  join BusinessUnitBase br on br.ParentBusinessUnit = br.BusinessUnit
)
select 
    r.*
from rcte r
order by r.buName
```

What happens is that the accounts that are returned are only for the first child without the grandchildren

Comment: Please show some sample data and your expected output

Comment: How two tables are connected?

Comment: 2 tables are connected, ill add some example data soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive common table expression can solve this.

**Sample data**

```
create table Account
(
  AccountId int,
  Name nvarchar(10),
  OwningBusiness int
);

insert into Account (AccountId, Name, OwningBusiness) values
(1, 'Alfred', 100),
(2, 'Batman', 200);

create table BusinessRelation
(
  BusinessUnit int,
  ParentBusinessUnit int,
  Name nvarchar(20)
);

insert into BusinessRelation (BusinessUnit, ParentBusinessUnit, Name) values
(100, null, 'Alfred Ltd.'),
(110, 100 , 'Alfred Holdings'),
(120, 100 , 'Alfred Rent-A-Car'),
(111, 110 , 'Alfred Supplies'),
(200, null, 'Batman Corp.'),
(210, 200 , 'Batman Automotive');
```

**Solution**

```
with rcte as
(
  select a.AccountId,
         a.Name as AccountName,
         br.Name as BusinessName,
         br.BusinessUnit,
         br.ParentBusinessUnit,
         convert(nvarchar(100), br.BusinessUnit) as Relation
  from Account a
  join BusinessRelation br
    on br.BusinessUnit = a.OwningBusiness
union all
  select r.AccountId,
         r.AccountName,
         br.Name,
         br.BusinessUnit,
         br.ParentBusinessUnit,
         convert(nvarchar(100), convert(nvarchar(10), r.Relation) + ' > ' + convert(nvarchar(10), br.BusinessUnit))
  from rcte r
  join BusinessRelation br
    on br.ParentBusinessUnit = r.BusinessUnit
)
select r.AccountId,
       r.AccountName,
       r.BusinessName,
       r.BusinessUnit,
       r.Relation
from rcte r
order by r.AccountId,
         r.BusinessUnit;
```

**Result**

```
AccountId  AccountName  BusinessName       BusinessUnit  Relation
---------  -----------  -----------------  ------------  ---------------
1          Alfred       Alfred Ltd.        100           100
1          Alfred       Alfred Holdings    110           100 > 110
1          Alfred       Alfred Supplies    111           100 > 110 > 111
1          Alfred       Alfred Rent-A-Car  120           100 > 120
2          Batman       Batman Corp.       200           200
2          Batman       Batman Automotive  210           200 > 210
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=d7280a35619c1d0a8fb5773ce46637fb) to see things in action.

---

**Update**

With new sample data.

```
create table BusinessRelation
(
  BusinessUnit nvarchar(13),
  ParentBusinessUnit nvarchar(13)
);

insert into BusinessRelation (BusinessUnit, ParentBusinessUnit) values
('7C6A387E-4231', '113D3FDB-7B8E'),
('A871C1DB-9B49', '7C6A387E-4231'),
('99E668AC-E183', '113D3FDB-7B8E'),
('61E240E0-5FDB', '964467C5-5EDB'),
('DF12F932-60DB', '964467C5-5EDB'),
('1A836362-883E', 'CB52AEC3-9EA2'),
('CDBF825B-51D6', '113D3FDB-7B8E'),
('C7839193-51D6', 'CDBF825B-51D6'),
('F8831375-51D6', 'CDBF825B-51D6'),
('BEA96E00-7675', '113D3FDB-7B8E'),
('556A4549-7675', 'BEA96E00-7675'),
('E4FD4238-A4F0', 'E178822F-AF63'),
('6CFE118A-62B0', '113D3FDB-7B8E');

declare @root nvarchar(13) = '113D3FDB-7B8E';

with rcte as
(
  select br.BusinessUnit,
         br.ParentBusinessUnit,
         convert(nvarchar(100), @root + ' > ' + br.BusinessUnit) as Relation,
         1 as Lvl
  from BusinessRelation br
  where br.ParentBusinessUnit = @root
union all
  select br.BusinessUnit,
         br.ParentBusinessUnit,
         convert(nvarchar(100), r.Relation + ' > ' + br.BusinessUnit),
         r.Lvl + 1
  from rcte r
  join BusinessRelation br
    on br.ParentBusinessUnit = r.BusinessUnit
)
select @root as ParentBusinessUnit,
       r.BusinessUnit,
       r.Relation,
       r.Lvl
from rcte r
order by r.Relation;
```

Results in:

```
ParentBusinessUnit  BusinessUnit   Relation                                       Lvl
------------------  -------------  ---------------------------------------------  ---
113D3FDB-7B8E       6CFE118A-62B0  113D3FDB-7B8E > 6CFE118A-62B0                  1
113D3FDB-7B8E       7C6A387E-4231  113D3FDB-7B8E > 7C6A387E-4231                  1
113D3FDB-7B8E       A871C1DB-9B49  113D3FDB-7B8E > 7C6A387E-4231 > A871C1DB-9B49  2
113D3FDB-7B8E       99E668AC-E183  113D3FDB-7B8E > 99E668AC-E183                  1
113D3FDB-7B8E       BEA96E00-7675  113D3FDB-7B8E > BEA96E00-7675                  1
113D3FDB-7B8E       556A4549-7675  113D3FDB-7B8E > BEA96E00-7675 > 556A4549-7675  2
113D3FDB-7B8E       CDBF825B-51D6  113D3FDB-7B8E > CDBF825B-51D6                  1
113D3FDB-7B8E       C7839193-51D6  113D3FDB-7B8E > CDBF825B-51D6 > C7839193-51D6  2
113D3FDB-7B8E       F8831375-51D6  113D3FDB-7B8E > CDBF825B-51D6 > F8831375-51D6  2
```

[Updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=785b0d906b242eb4d583e6396e031971).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, if I understand correctly this will go over an entire table and will check the relations of all records?

Comment: That is correct. If you want to select only one tree structure, then you add a `where` clause in the `rcte`, [like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=c654a35c181d2bc4dd7e4c4074d19c9e).

Comment: @Mike.G, anwer updated as well with new sample data.

Comment: I think I might not explain myself well enough in my desired result.
The result I am looking for is the Accounts that are in the tree, not the relations the accounts that are returned should be based on the relations but I do not need them in the output OR i am failing to understand the answer

Comment: If you do not need something, then [do not select it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=47bc3f9a49e5fb84f974b8993ec47a84)?

Comment: Yes indeed. i have made some alterations to the query but it seems that it will not stop running in some cases even after all the data is retrieved